# Trying to create a class that returns some random numbers

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a class that will return some random numbers.
Now i know how to create a bunch of random numbers and put them in a listbox using :

```
Random RndNmbrs = new Random();
int n = RndNmbrs.Next();
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(RndNmbrs.Next(0, 10));
}
```

But I want to put that code in a class and call it from `Program.cs`,
I have tried several things but I cant get it to work so please tell me how one is supposed to do this ?

Comment: Can you show what it is you have tried and got stuck with?

Comment: I would suggest doing some tutorials on OOP. Might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i did it like this :

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int Generate(int start, int end)
    {
        return rnd.Next(start, end);
    }
```

and then i call it with a for loop like so :

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.Add(NummersMaken.Generate(1,100));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple class to generate ranod numbers:

Generator class:

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    private Random _rndNmbrs = new Random();

    // Generate's a single random value
    public int Generate(int min, int max)
    {
        return _rndNmbrs.Next(min, max);
    }

    // Generate's a list of random values
    public List<int> Generate(int count, int min, int max)
    {
        var ret = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            ret.Add(_rndNmbrs.Next(min, max);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
var gen = new RandomNumberGenerator();
lstBubbleUnorderd.Items.AddRange(gen.Generate(10));
```

Comment: ok i did that now how do i call it ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hold the `Random` instance in the class as instance variable:

```
public class RandomGenerator
{ 
    private Random _rnd = new Random();

    public int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        return _rnd.Next(min, max);
    }
    // more methods...
}
```

You can use it for example in this way:

```
var generator = new RandomGenerator();
List<int> randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => generator.Next(0, 10)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to made this class as static. Then you don't need instantiate this class before using (because instantiating of this class does'n change it's behavior in any context).

```
public static class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    private static Random _randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

    // Generate's your random number
    public static int Generate()
    {
        return _rndNmbrs.Next();
    }
}
```

Then in code you can simply call

```
int RandomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Generate();
```

without creating new object.

Comment: May or may not be desired. Instead of a static class you could reuse the same `RandomNumberGenerator` instance with the same effect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933838/284240 and (acc. thread safety) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933863/284240

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing on thread safety. I didn't knew that.