# Displaying random GIF images from a specified location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have been working on my AI for a while now, but i can't seem to get my AI to display a random GIF image into my Picture Box from this location.

> C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\

Example of what's needed.

```
string[] imagePaths1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\images", "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

---

But instead of Audio files I need GIF images.

This is a sample of the code I have been using.

```
case "test":
                int image1;
                Random randim = new Random();
                image1 = randim.Next(0, 4);

                switch (image1)
                {
                    case 0:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\giphy.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\Party!.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\Staredown.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\tenor.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\idgaf-obama.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\homealone.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\giphy.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\fastsoccer.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\wallstreet.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;


                    case 9:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\DYjbX.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;



                }
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: That's very good to know thank you.

Comment: and i'm still learning, i was guessing it was the amount it will randomize threw that i added in the ' switch (image1)
                {

                    case 0:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\giphy.gif");
                        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
                        break;'

Comment: Right now it only randomizes the images i add in 'case 1, case 2, case 3 i want it to randomize all images in a folder instead. @mjwills

Comment: Woah the downvoters are out in force, let me rectify

Comment: You haven't asked us a question.

Comment: My question was how can i randomize the gif images in a folder to a picture box instead of the way i was originaly doing, i have tried multiple times so i thought i would ask for help, and the community was more than helpful, thank you for everyone's help so many great ideas! and pointers i can thank you enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may get you started:

```
var random = new Random();
var folder = @"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\images";

var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select((file, index) => new {file, index})
    .ToDictionary(z => z.index, y => y.file);

var randomPic = fileNames[random.Next(0, fileNames.Count)];
pictureBox2.Image = MediaTypeNames.Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(folder, randomPic));
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
```

The main thing is getting the filenames into a data structure. I use a `Dictionary` - you could just as easily use a `List` using:

```
var random = new Random();
var folder = @"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\images";

var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

var randomPic = fileNames[random.Next(0, fileNames.Count)];
pictureBox2.Image = MediaTypeNames.Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(folder, randomPic));
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
```

Then randomly choose a filename and populate `pictureBox2` with that filename.

*You should also [strongly consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643421/correct-method-of-a-static-random-next-in-c) moving `random` to be a `static` field.*

Comment: Why create a dictionary from an index? Why not just create an array (from which you can just index naturally)?

Comment: That would also work @Enigmativity. I used `Dictionary` partly to try and teach something new to the OP. I'll change the answer to show the `List` code explicitly - thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following :-

```
var basePath =
    @"C:\Users\scatt\Desktop\Marvel-J.A.R.V.I.S-Personal-Assistant-Winform-C--master\Marvel J.A.R.V.I.S Personal Assistant\Resources\AIPICS\";

var pics = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(basePath, "*.gif").ToArray();
var randomPic = pics.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
pictureBox2.Image = MediaTypeNames.Image.FromFile(randomPic);
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.CancelAsync();
```

Comment: Wow that is a much easier visual, not exactly what i mean but easier thank you!!!

Comment: I didn't mean to i pressed the wrong button. @ Keith Nicholas

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it.

Comment: you didn't downvote me :) you don't have enough reputation to do that yet

Comment: Please don't use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate entropy. A `Guid` is guaranteed to be unique, not random. Always use a RNG instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity  I just did some randomness tests for using it to sort vs random, and it is pretty indistinguishable.

Comment: if anything, random seems a bit less random :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas - It may well currently be random, but that's not the point. It's not guaranteed to be random, just unique. You shouldn't rely on any apparent randomness in guids.

Comment: been like that for nearly 20 years :)  I'm all good with using it :)

Comment: I suspect the main issue with this solution, as is, is performance. The way this is done means you need to take the hit of producing `n` number of `Guid`s (gets slower as the number of files increases) *and* sort the `Guid`s. That is likely slower than generating a single random number. _To reduce the memory consumption, you could consider using https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs rather than `OrderBy` and `First`._

Comment: given this is loading files, the performance cost of a shuffle isn't even significant